# Snowflake regexp_substr to fetch folder name as a column from s3 bucket

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-substr

Can someone help me fetch "Client name" using regexp_substr from below path in Snowflake. The client names here can have spaces or underscores

> s3://student-com/student-to-employee/student1/Student_Party/20221223/Client
> ABC/Employee_1st_data_20221223115427_4048241.csv
>
> s3://student-com/student-to-employee/student1/Student_Party/20221223/Client_XYZ/Employee_1st_data_20221223115427_4048241.csv

I used something like this:

> select regexp_substr(METADATA$FILENAME, '(.+\/)*(.+.csv)$', 1,1,'e')
> as name

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sql
select regexp_substr(METADATA$FILENAME, '([^/]+)/[^/]*\.csv$', 1,1,'e') as name
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FwsBt1/3).

*Details*:

- `([^/]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\.csv` - `.csv`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, however this gives Employee_1st_data as output, I want to see Client_XYZ or Client ABC as output.

Comment: @Sara I was trying to follow the original regex logic. I replaced the solution to the one that returns the strings you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If client name is always the subfolder preceding the file name, you can use `split_part`

```
select split_part(col,'/',-2)
```